# How and should I add class objects to the Resources folder?

Tags: visual-studio, class, resources, .net-standard

I am creating a .NET standard application and want to store an object class into my resources folder. Is there a way I can initialize an existing class to store into the resources folder, or is it better to create and initialize all the variables during runtime?

Comment: Please show relevant code?

Comment: I don't really have code yet, and I don't have much experience with Visual Studio's resources. I simply want to know if it is possible and viable to add a class object as a resource.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "class object as a resource". If you're new, I suggest starting with beginner tutorials on developing C# apps in Visual Studio.